# time complexity for my function

Tags: computational-complexity

What is the time complexity for the following function? (the basic operation is the innermost loop body's assignment).

```
function f(n)
    r ← 0
    m ← 1
    for i ← 1 to n do
        m ← 3 × m
        for j ← 1 to m do
            r ← r + j
    return r
```

Multiple Choices:

Θ(n^3)

Θ(3^n)

Θ(n*log(n))

Θ(n)

Θ(n^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rewrite it a bit:

```
function f(n)
    r ← 0
    for i ← 1 to n do
        for j ← 1 to 3^i do
            r ← r + j
    return r
```

So we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n 3^i = \frac{3^{n+1} - 1}{3 - 1 } - 1
$$
evaluations of the inner loop.

Comment: Yes, so the order of magnitude of number the of steps is $O(n3^n)$. $3^n$ is good for  a lower bound but is not good for an upper bound. I don't see if $\Theta(n3^n)$ as possible choice.

Comment: Simply because it is not $O(n 3^n)$, just $O(3^n)$.

Comment: Oh, stupid of me. The $n$ is in the summation when we compute the sum of the geometric series...